# Oracle Remove Duplicates and Update Rows in a Table with a Value from Another Table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, window-functions

In my associates table I have 4,978 people with at least 1 duplicate.

```
asscssn     | count(*)
---------     --------
123456789      8
987654321      5
234567890      5
```

Each duplicate for a person has a unique id (asscid) in the associates table.

```
asscid | asscssn
------  -------
53492    987654321
53365    987654321
53364    987654321
52104    987654321
50185    987654321
```

My cases table has a case tied to each asscid

```
docketnumber | asscid
-----------    -------
2010JV0000     53492
2010JV1111     53365
2010JV2222     53364
2010JV3333     52104
2010JV4444     50185
```

I would like to take each person that has a duplicate, grab the latest asscid that person has from the associates table and update the cases table.  Results would be:

```
  docketnumber | asscid
    -----------    -------
    2010JV0000     53492
    2010JV1111     53492
    2010JV2222     53492
    2010JV3333     53492
    2010JV4444     53492
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select c.docketnumber, max_asscid
from cases c join
     (select a.*, max(asscid) over (partition by asscssn) as max_asscid
      from associations a
     ) a
     on c.asscid = a.asscid;
```

This assumes that the "latest" `asscid` is the one with the largest value.  If you have another column that specifies the ordering (such as a date), then you can use `first_value()` instead.

EDIT:

If you actually want to update the data:

```
update cases c
    set assc_id = (select max_asscid
                   from (select a.*, max(asscid) over (partition by asscssn) as max_asscid
                         from associations a
                         where asscssn is not null
                        ) a
                   where a.asscid = c.asscid
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. @gordon linoff.  The query works.  Where do I put the update statement?

Comment: the script works beautifully.  I did notice one thing.  I have 33K records where asscssn is null and it changed all those records to the largest asscid.  To ignore records where asscssn is null do I put the `and asscssn is not null` after the  `where a.asscid = c.asscid` ?

Comment: @belmer01 . . . You would add `where assc_id is not null` after the `set`.

Comment: That didn't quite work.  asscid will never be null because it's the primary key.  In the associates table I want to `select max_asscid`  as long as asscssn is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` after getting the latest `asscid`. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oe8RVjJ8Y5nSQjLG51Q4Jf/1).

```
select
    docketnumber,
    q.asscid
from table2
cross join
(
  select
    max(asscid) as asscid
  from table1
) q
```

output:

```
| docketnumber | asscid |
| ------------ | ------ |
| 2010JV0000   | 53492  |
| 2010JV1111   | 53492  |
| 2010JV2222   | 53492  |
| 2010JV3333   | 53492  |
| 2010JV4444   | 53492  |
```

Comment: Thanks @zealous.  I need to group by asscssn.  I have close to 5k people that each have multiple duplicates.  I think you're query would take the highest asscid in the whole table and copy it to all others.  This would break the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking for an `update` statement - which none of the other answers provided so far.

The syntax of `update` queries tend to be rather specific to each database.  Now that it has been clarified that you are using Oracle, I would suggest using a correlated subquery.

You can either self-join the `associates` table:

```
update cases c
set asscid = (
    select max(a1.asscid) 
    from associates a
    inner join associates a1 on a1.asscssn = a.asscssn
    where a.asscid = c.asscid
)
```

Or you can also use window functions:

```
update cases c
set asscid = (
    select max_asscid
    from (
        select asscid, max(asscid) over(partition by asscssn) max_asscid
        from associates
    ) a
    where a.asscid = c.asscid
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6fc56dc41d58b297567e09a01845880b)**: after the `update` query is executed, the `cases` table contains:

```
DOCKETNUMBER | ASSCID
:----------- | -----:
2010JV0000   |  53492
2010JV1111   |  53492
2010JV2222   |  53492
2010JV3333   |  53492
2010JV4444   |  53492
```